# SymPy: solving overdetermined system of linear equations

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

I know that SymPy is able to solve overdetermined systems of linear equations, but I'm running into the following problem:

Let's start with something that works:

[image: equation]

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
matrix = Matrix([
    [1, 0, 0, symbols('A')],
    [0, 1, 0, symbols('B')],
    [0, 0, 1, symbols('C')]])
linsolve(matrix, (x,y,z))
```

**output:** {(A, B, C)}

And now with one extra equation:

[image]

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
matrix = Matrix([
    [1, 0, 0, symbols('A')],
    [0, 1, 0, symbols('B')],
    [0, 0, 1, symbols('C')],
    [2, 1, 0, symbols('D')]])
linsolve(matrix, (x,y,z))
```

**output:** EmptySet()

There isn't any output anymore although obviously there still is a solution. Wolfram Alpha for example will still present this solution:

input:

```
1x+0y+0z=A, 0x+1y+0z=B, 0x+0y+1z=C, 2x+y=D
```

output:

```
D = 2 A + B, x = A, y = B, z = C
```

In this example it's obvious the last equation wasn't needed to solve for x,y,z but the problem is that I have to solve thousands of these systems, each one with up to 14 variables so I can't go through this manually to check which equations could be dropped. (It wouldn't be so obvious as in this toy example as well)

Comment: Seems like a bug. The method [`sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.gauss_jordan_solve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html?highlight=gauss_jordan_solve#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.gauss_jordan_solve) is raising `ValueError: Linear system has no solution`, and it is supposed to be able to solve under- and overdetermined systems (so either there is something wrong in the implementation or the documentation).

Comment: Why use `linsolve` instead of `rref`?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow it to solve for more variables, it will do so. Here, all A-D are allowed, but you could allow for only D, too:

```
>>> linsolve(matrix, (x,y,z)+var("A:D"))
{(-B/2 + D/2, B, C, -B/2 + D/2, B, C, D)}
```

You could also investigate using `connected_components` the way `solve` does to separate out equations which do not depend on others.